# Как посчитать количество итерации рекурсивной функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def F(n):
    print('*')
    if n > 0:
        F(n-2)
        F(n // 2)
        F(n // 2)

F(5)
```

Нужно посчитать количество звездочек в функции, то есть количество проходов стека, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто посчитать и сложить:

```
def F(n):
    print('*')
    c = 1
    if n > 0:
        c += F(n-2)
        c += F(n // 2)
        c += F(n // 2)
    return c

print(F(5))
# 34
```

Answer (score 3):

Возможно слишком сложный способ - с декоратором, но позволяющий не трогать код функции

```
def countCalls(fun):
    def inner(*args):
        inner.calls += 1
        return fun(*args)
    inner.calls = 0
    return inner

@countCalls
def F(n):
    print('*')
    if n > 0:
        F(n-2)
        F(n // 2)
        F(n // 2)

F(5)
print(F.calls)  # 34
```

Comment: Ответ, конечно, правильный, но можно ли это сделать без декоратора? И если да то как? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Сделайте глобальную переменную и параллельно с print'ом увеличивайте на 1